# Rearranging different views/windows in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am wondering if it's possible to have a "panel"/view on both sides of my editor in eclipse?

For example, package explorer on the left, editor in the middle (that's the default arrangement) and then to add the debug view on the right. I don't want to split the editor horizontally or vertically but rather to have a whole new panel on the right for the debug.

Comment: You can drag (the title is the handle) and drop views and editors to wherever you want. The new arrangement can then be saved as a new perspective (see the _Window_ menu).

Comment: I can drag any view but unfortunately can't drop it to the right hand side of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, definitely you can, [image]

first , you have to close whichever window is on the right side, except the editor and then drag the console to the right.I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks a bunch!!  I always had detached windows on the right side so it didn't "want" to snap into plays. After closing everything it worked as I wanted. I fell very silly now haha